# Simple toggle function with IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm facing a problem with IE6.

I took the toggle function from this [website](http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/) but when I apply it to my page I get the error (only in IE6):

> Could not get the display property.
>   Invalid argument.

I can get the display property, but the error is thrown when I want to set to the new value.

EDIT:
I know that several developers have faced this problem. So if it can help: **the table-row property is not managed by internet explorer 6**!

In my case, even when I set the display property to '' I wasn't seeing anything but it was because I applied a class to my element that hide them on load, so the default display would be, hide and when you set the display property to '' IE set it to the default display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to set the display-property to "table-row" by any change? That is not supported by IE6.

A tip is to set display to an empty string. It makes the browser use the default value for the element.